# Passing configuration to Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject

I need to pass an IConfiguration to my DbClient class and my repositories depend on this DbClient. I couldn't get this to work.

My DbClient:

```
public class DbClient
{
   public DbClient(IConfiguration config)
   {
      // Perform some initialization
   }
}
```

My repository depends on the DbClient:

```
public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
   private DbClient _client;
   public MyRepository(DbClient client)
   {
      _client = client;
   }
}
```

My Bindings class

```
public class NinjectBindings : NinjectModule
{
   public override void Load()
   {
      Bind<DbClient>().To<DbClient>(); // ?? Not sure about this
      Bind<IMyRepository>().To<MyRepository>();
   }
}
```

And the Main in my console app:

```
static void Main()
{
   var config = new Configuration();
   config.AddJsonFile("settings.json");

   var kernel = new StandardKernel();
   kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

   var myRepository = kernel.Get<IMyRepository>();
}
```

What am I missing? What do I need to do to pass IConfiguration into the DbClient  and make sure the repository initializes properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind `IConfiguration`.
You can do it in `Load` method:

```
Bind<IConfiguration>().ToMethod(ctx =>
{
    var config = new Configuration();
    config.AddJsonFile("settings.json");
    return config;
});
```

Or in `Main` method:

```
kernel.Bind<IConfiguration>().ToMethod(...);
```

Binding type depends on your need. Maybe you should bind config as constant without context dependency.

Also line `Bind<DbClient>().To<DbClient>();` isn't necessary because `DbClient` will be automatically bind to self.